# Footer, is not anchored at the bottom, Scrolling with page

Tags: css, width, footer

Heres my page http://sketchedneo.com/indexex.php

SO the footer is in a Include php

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 0px;
    right:0px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #c9c9c9;
    height: 125px;
    color: #868686;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 3px solid #EBEBEB;

}
```

The footer needs to be at the bottom of the page (like stack overflow) Instead of the scrolling with the page.

Anyone know the solution please?

Comment: Do you want width of footer equal to browser or position fixed not working

Comment: The footer needs to be the footer on this site (stackoverflow) So its 100% across the screen, no matter what screen size is.

Comment: add right:0px;  - Has worked! Thank you

Comment: You have not added position:fixed in your page.Go and fix it

Comment: Though it has now gained another issue, the footer isnt sitting at the bottom, its scrolling with the page.

Comment: Added, position fixed (updated code in question)

Comment: If you are still having problems please see the answer I received at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103910/create-footer-element-located-beneath-the-screen

Answer (score 1):

```
position:fixed;
    left: 0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; 
    background: #c9c9c9;

    color: #868686;
    border-top: 3px solid #EBEBEB;  
    text-align: center;  z-index: 1000;
```

Do like this and also you have defined #footer in line 1465 second time

Comment: The footer is still following the scroll of the page.

Comment: So remove it from php include and put it above header div?

Comment: Are you joking , the link you given now has fixed footer(try in mozilla firefox)

Comment: No, even in Mozilla (I use chrome mainly) It still scrolls with page. The footer needs to be at the bottom of the page (so you only see it, if you scroll down)