# Create footer element located beneath the screen

Tags: html, css, layout, footer

I have a page that does not fill the entire screen's height, but I want a footer to stay just below the screen, so that it appears right when you start scrolling - no matter the person's screen height.

How do I accomplish this using CSS?

**EDIT**

I have tried:

```
#footer{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:100%;
}
```

This works, but it gets in the way if my page *does* go over the screen's height. I really need compatibility for both types of pages.

Comment: ad the edit) try setting `margin-top: -HEIGHT`

Comment: @IanKuca the height depends on the page's size

Comment: The height of the footer? That's a bummer.

Comment: @IanKuca I tried typing the footer's height in. This works, but the footer gets in the way if my actual page does go over the screen's height. If the page does go over the screen's height, I want the footer right underneath everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of the layout you describe:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head><title>Hidden Footer</title></head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        Content here
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Footer here
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; }

#content { min-height: 100%; }
#footer { background: #ccc; }
```

Comment: I tried just your sample code, and it works great, no matter how long my `content` is! Thank you.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without adding those CSS attributes to `html` and `body`? I like to keep these tags free of these types of attributes.

Comment: By 'attributes' do you mean the CSS applied to those elements? If so, then sadly, no. Those styles are necessary to push the footer below the viewport. (I wouldn't have any reservations about adding CSS to those two elements. It is done all the time for layouts that are 'viewport-relative') The content area will not expand to 100% without the body and html containers allowing for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 40px; /* free space for the footer */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* don't add padding to the actual height */
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The page you linked has a fixed header.  The rest of the body scrolls appropriately.

Look into fixed CSS headers/footers to replicate the effect.

Comment: What's your screen's height? When I resize my browser on the linked page, the footer will always appear right after I start scrolling, as long as I keep some white space after the contact form.

Comment: How would I use a fixed footer? I don't want the footer to appear immediately.