# Footer not at bottom of page

Tags: html, css, footer

I am trying to keep my footer at the bottom of the page. The first way I tried it, the footer would be above the bottom of the page and the background would show. This was with position:static; (like the following image)

[image: image goes here]

The second way I tried is with an absolute footer. This puts the footer at the bottom of pages where there isn't enough content to scroll but on pages with the scroll, it sits at the bottom of the window when it loads and is on top of content.It is not the bottom of the page.

Here is my current code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="slideshow"></div>
        <div id="clear"></div>
        <div id="boxes">
            <div id="box">
                <div id="boxheader"></div>
                <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="box">
                <div id="boxheader"></div>
                <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="box">
                <div id="boxheader"></div>
                <div id="box3" class="box"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Content</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
div#container{
  position:relative;
  margin: 4px;
}
#boxes{
  width: 960px;
  margin: 50px auto 0px auto;
}
#footer {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103910/create-footer-element-located-beneath-the-screen

Comment: Is there something wrong with using `position: fixed`?

Comment: @Explosion Pills unless doing some "loops in the air", u will end up with the footer covering part of the site, with no scroll bar to un-hide hidden piece.

Comment: Dear OP, I am not familiar with a site that the footer is at the bottom of the view port, it is always at the bottom of the full page. If u r familiar with one, poit us to it, or check it's css yourself to see how they did it. I remember something about using JS to achive it...not clean

Comment: You should use class boxheader instead id(same for box), because you use it multiple times. I don't see id clear in your css.

Comment: I did not paste clear but it is in the css. Thanks for the boxheader. fixed that

Comment: Dear OP, this question is just too, specific,(and couldn't quiet actually figure out what your circumstances are) so could you just point us to the problem, i mean a url or something, then you might edit it out once thats solved.

Comment: Are you trying to create a ["sticky footer"](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)?

Answer (score 0):

set

`html, body {
    height: 100%;
 }`

wrap the entire content before the footer in a div.

`.wrapper {
     height:auto !important;
     min-height:100%;
}`

You can adjust min-height to your liking based on how much of the footer you want to show in the bottom of the browser-window. If set it to 90%, 10% of the footer will show before scrolling.

So in your example

`<body style="height: 100%">
    <div id="container" style="min-height: 90%; height: auto !important;">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="slideshow"></div>
        <div id="clear"></div>
        <div id="boxes">
            <div id="box">
                <div id="boxheader"></div>
                <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="box">
                <div id="boxheader"></div>
                <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="box">
                <div id="boxheader"></div>
                <div id="box3" class="box"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Content</div>`

Answer (score -1):

I've used the method described in the article liked below many times, and have had no problems with it:

http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Hope it helps!